# run anonymous function (IIFE) on unittest using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have file index with anonymous function or IIFE like this below

```
(async()=> todo list logic)()
```

I want to call this anonymous function on my test case,
is there any way to run this anonymous func on my unit test case?
or is there any way to call this function using typescript code?

thanks in advance

Comment: In IIFE automatically runs just because it's there. What exactly do you want to call on it separately?

Comment: i want to create unittest of it, so i have to run the file when i run my unittest, the problem is on ther, how do i run IIFE file @tevemadar

Comment: The whole idea of an IIFE is that it is _Immediately Invoked_. This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: actually i can use like marco said below, but it seems i need to do a little refactor of the code which prohibited for me to touch the code, but i will discuss to my lead about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not call it explicitly from your tests. I recommend creating a pure function and an additional IFFE wrapper. This way you can import your pure function into your tests.

```js
// foo.js
function foo() {}

export default foo
```

```js
// foo-wrapper.js

(() => {
  foo()
})()
```

```js
// foo.test.js

import foo from './foo.js'
```

Comment: i have tried this once before, but the problem is , it seems i need to do a little refactor code there which i prohibited for me to touch the code, but maybe i can discuss this to my lead, thank you marco

Comment: and the downside is, it will run twice for foo() , if i call foo() on my unittest, it will run the IFFE and foo()

Comment: No, in both cases `foo` is executed once. Once in your tests and once immediately on runtime.